# How to fix the datetime format in a column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with the below DateTime data:

```html
DateTime
13/09/2018 6:16:58 PM
22/09/2018 5:16:07 PM
23/09/2018 10:52:54 AM
23/09/2018 3:01:12 AM
23/09/2018 5:47:44 AM
23/09/2018 7:06:44 PM
23/09/2018 8:46:25 AM
3/9/2018 16:00
3/9/2018 19:39
30/09/2018 9:52:35 PM
6/9/2018 15:49
6/9/2018 16:15
6/9/2018 16:41
6/9/2018 20:02
7/9/2018 13:49
7/9/2018 20:43
7/9/2018 22:26
7/9/2018 9:32
8/9/2018 1:12
8/9/2018 14:24
8/9/2018 16:18
9/9/2018 13:45
```

As it can be seen the format of DateTime in this column is mixed. I tried the following piece of code to standardize the format and extract some results out of that data:

```py
#Converting the column into DateTime objects

pf['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(pf['DateTime'], errors = 'coerce')


# Set up a standard DateTime like format throughout the column
# pf is the data frame

pf['DateTime'].dt.strftime("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")

# Grouping the DateTime column by Month
grp = pf.groupby(pf['DateTime'].dt.to_period('M'))

for d in grp:
    print('d',d)
```

But strangely, even after setting the format of the DateTime columns, the dates are being picked out as month and the groups I am getting are :

```html
d (Period('2018-03', 'M')

d (Period('2018-06', 'M')

d (Period('2018-07', 'M')

d (Period('2018-08', 'M')

d (Period('2018-09', 'M')
```

The fact is the values 6,7,8 are the dates of month 9 and are mistakenly picked up as month. The expected outcome should be:

```html
d (Period('2018-09', 'M')
```

How to set up the columns in such a way that it doesn't pick the date as a month.

Comment: I think your initial column is just strings .... not actual datetime objects

Comment: You mean initial values in the column ? How to fix that?

Comment: use `str` api of Pandas and `rstrip` or `replace` to remove AM and PM

Comment: Thank you, Sorry I forgot to mention that I do convert the whole column into a DateTime object. I added that in an edit to the question now. Secondly, the values with AM/PM are not getting picked up wrong, its the other values with 6,7,8,3 dates, that is getting picked up as months

Comment: I tried str.rstrip and then the groupby, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: after you do `to_datetime()` print your dataframe ... they should all look uniform ... if you really want a string representation `df['datestring'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime(...)` ... it doesnt modify the column it returns a new column so you need to save it into a column ... but really not sure why  you would want a string instead of dates

Comment: After i do to_datetime() and print, i still get wrong values like:
```python
9/23/2018 10:52
9/23/2018 3:01
9/23/2018 5:47
9/23/2018 7:06
9/23/2018 8:46
3/9/2018 16:00
3/9/2018 19:39
9/30/2018 9:52
6/9/2018 15:49
6/9/2018 16:15
6/9/2018 16:41
6/9/2018 20:02
7/9/2018 9:32
```

Comment: How should I declare that 3,6,7,8 are not months but dates

Comment: what do you mean by 3 6 7 8

Comment: The dates 3,6,7,8 in the data, which are being picked up as months.

Comment: I don't think so https://ibb.co/L0sXrDQ the picture in the link is from my test

Comment: Yes, in your output as well, the same result is coming, but the fact is its all data of only one month...9th month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `to_datetime` function directly assumes that the format is `%d/%m/%Y`. The `%d` is handling a zero padded value for the days, so it doesn't recognize that `6/9/2018` means 6th of September 2018.

To handle that problem you need to use `dayfirst` of the [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function. By doing so you get the following:

Without `dayfirst`:

```
pf['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(pf['DateTime'])
pf
Out[69]: 
              DateTime
0  2018-09-13 18:16:58
1  2018-09-22 17:16:07
2  2018-09-23 10:52:54
3  2018-09-23 03:01:12
4  2018-09-23 05:47:44
5  2018-09-23 19:06:44
6  2018-09-23 08:46:25
7  2018-03-09 16:00:00
8  2018-03-09 19:39:00
9  2018-09-30 21:52:35
10 2018-06-09 15:49:00
11 2018-06-09 16:15:00
12 2018-06-09 16:41:00
13 2018-06-09 20:02:00
14 2018-07-09 13:49:00
15 2018-07-09 20:43:00
16 2018-07-09 22:26:00
17 2018-07-09 09:32:00
18 2018-08-09 01:12:00
19 2018-08-09 14:24:00
20 2018-08-09 16:18:00
21 2018-09-09 13:45:00
```

With `dayfirst`:

```
    pf = pd.DataFrame(d)
pf['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(pf['DateTime'],  dayfirst=True)
pf
Out[72]: 
              DateTime
0  2018-09-13 18:16:58
1  2018-09-22 17:16:07
2  2018-09-23 10:52:54
3  2018-09-23 03:01:12
4  2018-09-23 05:47:44
5  2018-09-23 19:06:44
6  2018-09-23 08:46:25
7  2018-09-03 16:00:00
8  2018-09-03 19:39:00
9  2018-09-30 21:52:35
10 2018-09-06 15:49:00
11 2018-09-06 16:15:00
12 2018-09-06 16:41:00
13 2018-09-06 20:02:00
14 2018-09-07 13:49:00
15 2018-09-07 20:43:00
16 2018-09-07 22:26:00
17 2018-09-07 09:32:00
18 2018-09-08 01:12:00
19 2018-09-08 14:24:00
20 2018-09-08 16:18:00
21 2018-09-09 13:45:00
```